# How to set avro compression codec for mapper output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression, avro, codec

When using Avro as the output format of the mapper in a hadoop MR task, how can I set the compression codec?

The old ["mapred" API](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroJob.html) provided this method:

```
org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroJob.setOutputCodec(JobConf job, String codec)
```

However, that is absent in the newer ["mapreduce" API](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapreduce/AvroJob.html). How can I set the codec in the newer "mapreduce" API?

I've naively tried to use job configuration to set the codec but wasn't successful:

```java
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
  [..]
  Job job = new Job(getConf());
  job.setJarByClass(MapReduceExample.class);
  job.setJobName("MRExample");
  // hm .. this doesn't seem to do work, output still has "null" codec
  job.getConfiguration().set(AvroJob.CONF_OUTPUT_CODEC,
                             CodecFactory.deflateCodec(6).toString());

  job.setMapperClass(ExampleMapper.class);
  [..]
  AvroJob.setMapOutputKeySchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
  AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(job, Schema.create(Schema.Type.BYTES));
  // here I was hoping to use something like
  // AvroJob.setMapOutputCodec(job, "deflate")

  [..]
  return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

When I open the resulting avro with python

```python
>>> from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
>>> from avro.io import DatumReader
>>> av_fh = open("output/part-r-00000.avro", "rb")
>>> av_rd = DataFileReader(av_fh, DatumReader())
>>> av_rd.codec
'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when I change the following lines

```
job.getConfiguration().set(AvroJob.CONF_OUTPUT_CODEC,
                           CodecFactory.deflateCodec(6).toString());
```

to

```
FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
job.getConfiguration().set(AvroJob.CONF_OUTPUT_CODEC,
                           DataFileConstants.DEFLATE_CODEC);
```